# Is there a way to serve julia from the cgi-bin directory with apache?

Tags: apache, julia, centos6, cgi-bin

I have a user who wants to serve output of julia files from an apache webserver.

Placing the code in there, adding .jl to AddHandler, and chmod 775 the file gets a 500 internal server error.

helloworld.jl:  -rwxr-xr-x
`println("hello world")`

Here is what is displayed from apache:

````
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.```
````

Comment: _More information about this error may be available in the server error log._

Comment: ```Premature end of script headers: helloworld.jl```
```[Wed Jun 26 16:42:20 2019] [error] [client ] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/julia/helloworld.jl' failed``` It looks like it might just need to load a Julia CGI library?

Comment: Also, Apache clears the environment variables that its processes see for security reasons, and those include ones Julia uses to find its configuration files and  packages. You may need to configure Apache's conf files to set the OS-appropriate environment variables manually.